# What files should I delete to completely remove WordPress front-end?

Tags: wordpress, frontend

How do you completely delete the wordpress frontend?

I have made a pupil management solution using the backend of wordpress so have no use for the frontend. I don't want to just disable it I want to completely delete the frontend, apart from the wp-admin login form of course!

Comment: Are you saying you want your system to simply show a login page when browsing http://sitename.com if you aren't logged in, and once the user logs in, it simply goes to the wp-admin panel?

Comment: Im saying I want to completely remove the frontend, so no pages posts are available. Maybe I could make a theme for this purpose. I did think about just deleting index.php in the frontend but I imagine other files may become effected.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [WordPress › Absolute Privacy « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/absolute-privacy/)

You can lock down the front end, disable news feeds, redirect all page views to the login page, and more.

Using a plugin like it is much better than editing Wordpress core files or functions to remove the front end.

Just use any of the default Wordpress themes - like twentythirteen - as it doesn't matter which one because no one will see it anyway.

Comment: This plugin's last update was 8 years ago!

Comment: Duh, this question was asked 7 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to configure your site for registered users only, take a look at this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/restricted-site-access/

You probably don't need to delete anything for this to work.

Comment: The pupil tracking system is in the backend of wordpress this is more for wordpress solutions using the frontend. THanks for taking a look

Comment: Why not just create a theme that redirects to wp-admin? Wonder if that would work?